# Count occurences of characters in a string and return an integer list showing how many times each letter in the alphabet appears

Tags: f#

I need to make a recursive function which takes a string and counts how many times each letter in the alphabet appears in the string. It should return an integer list such that "abe" returns [1;1;0;0;1;0;0;0;0 and so on]

This is for a school assignment. I have tried making the string to a char list which I can use pattern matching on, but to no avail. I will show in code an example of this.

My 2 BEST tries:

1.

```
let rec histogram (src:string) : int list =
    let dat = src.ToLower()
    let trt = Seq.toList dat
    match alphabet with
        | []-> []
        | head::tail when List.contains head trt -> |> Seq.countBy (fun x -> x) |> Seq.map snd :: histogram (System.String.Concat(Array.ofList(tail)))
        | _tail -> histogram (System.String.Concat(Array.ofList(tail)))
```

2. ````
   let rec histogram (src:string) : int list =
       let dat = src.ToLower()
       let trt = Seq.toList dat
       match trt with
           | []-> []
           | head::tail when List.exists ((=) head) alphabet -> List.countBy id ::histogram (System.String.Concat(Array.ofList(tail))
           | _::tail -> convText (System.String.Concat(Array.ofList(tail)))```
   ````

Comment: What's the problem with your attempts?

Answer (score 0):

I dont't think you should use recursion here. Besides all, it iterates a string for each letter, so it has complexity O(n^2). Try this:

```
let histogram (src:string) : int list =
    let lettersCount = [|for i in 0..25 -> 0|]
    for c in src.ToLower() do
        let index = int c - int 'a'
        lettersCount.[index]<-lettersCount.[index]+1
    lettersCount |> Seq.toList
```

I understand, that is is not too functional way, but it is better for this task

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for deleted comment. I somehow did not happen to notice, than you actually are to make a recursive function.
Look, you problem is that you are trying to mach an `alphabet` collection which is not passed to a function (probably it is defined in a closure), so it never changes through recursion.
This is a really crazy task for a recursion, but you can try something like this:

```
let rec histogram (src:string) : int list =
    match src.ToLower()|>Seq.toList with
    |head::tail ->
        String.Join("", tail)
        |>histogram
        |>List.mapi(fun i c -> if i=(int head - int 'a') then c+1 else c)
    |[] -> [for i in 1..26 -> 0]
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand everything. Out of curiosity how would you do it, if it didn't have to be a recursive function?

Comment: I'll undelete my first comment, there is a non-recursive solution.